# Prove that there are infinite number of mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\mathbb{Q} ?$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that  there are infinite number of mapping from  $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\mathbb{Q} ?$

My attempt : If i take $f(x) = [x]^{x} $ where $[.]$ denote the greatest integer function .then it will be satisfied the onto mapping

Im confusing that how to prove this

Comment: Why would it land in $\mathbb{Q}$?  For example, $\lfloor\sqrt5\rfloor^{\sqrt5}=2^{\sqrt5}$ is transcendental by Gelfond–Schneider.

Comment: Also, $\lfloor x\rfloor^x$ is generally not defined for $x<0$.

Comment: How about $f_n(x)=nx$ when $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $0$ when $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$, $n$ is any natural number.

Comment: thanks u @Conifold

Comment: @Gae.S. ya i noticed that

Comment: my  mistake, i didn't noticed that @user10354138

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=x$ for $x$ rational, $f_n(\sqrt 2)=n$ and $f_n(x)=0$ for any irrational number other than $\sqrt 2$.

These are distinct maps from $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb Q$.